# pip install always downloading to anaconda3 file, I cant use the packages with pycharm

Tags: macos, pip, pycharm, anaconda, gurobi

I am using pycharm and currently trying to import a gurobipy package to my project. A long time ago I installed anaconda and I see that when I pip install, it always downloads it to /anaconda3/bin/python. So I have deleted this anaconda3 file but still not able to pip install to the project I want to.

Note: I am working on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to check which virtual Python environment is currently active in your shell. Also, try using

```
python -m pip install <package>
```

instead of just `pip install <package>`. This guarantees that the new package is installed into your current Python environment. Otherwise, it may happen that there is another installation of the `pip` binary in your PATH that gets precedence.